# Solve for $n$ in $4\log_2(n)=n,\,$ i.e. $\,n^4 = 2^n$?

Tags: logarithms

As the title suggests, my log skills are pretty lacking. Need to learn how to get from $4\log_2(n)=n$ to $n=16$ ($\log$ base $2$). I've searched Google and it seems I am missing some core concept here. I really appreciate the help or guidance.

Comment: **Hints**: $a \log (n) = \log(n^a)$; $\log_b (n) = x \rightarrow n = b^x$. I assume you are solving in $\mathbb{N}$, that is, the only answers you care about are ones that are positive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Lambert W-function, which can't be solved with elementary functions (but can be expressed as an infinite sum using the Lagrange inversion forumula)

However just by trying random powers of 2 you can get an integer solution of $n = 16$, probably the easiest way.

Comment: ..which is btw the only solution in $\mathbb N$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $4\log_2(n) = n$ is the same as $n^4 = 2^n$. As $n=16$ is indeed a solution, the only question left is whether there is any other natural number that satisfies that equality. But, $2^n$ (eventually) grows faster than $n^4$ as $n$ grows (more precisely, $2^n > n^4$ for all $n$ bigger than $16$ - induction or calculus can show this).

Answer (score 0):

$4\log_2n=n\iff2^{4\log_2n}=2^n\iff n^4=2^n\iff n=2^k$ , since $n\in\mathbb{N}\iff2^{4k}=2^{2^k}\to$ $\to4k=2^k\iff k=2^{k-2}$. Can you take it from here ? :-)

---

$4\log_2n=n\iff4\dfrac{\ln n}{\ln 2}=n\iff\dfrac{\ln n}n=\underbrace{\dfrac{\ln2}4}_\text{constant}.\quad$ Now draw the graphic of $\dfrac{\ln x}x$ ,  and tell me what you notice. :-)